# Previous date value next to current date column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with values of meter readings for every day. First, I want the sum of all meter readings for a given date. That is easy to achieve with a group by clause. What I have not been able to do is get the sum of meter readings for the previous date in the table.

Original Data:

```
Ddate      ---- Value
2019-09-11 ---- 10
2019-09-11 ---- 20
2019-09-11 ---- 30
2019-09-10 ---- 15
2019-09-10 ---- 15
2019-09-10 ---- 15
2019-09-09 ---- 10
2019-09-09 ---- 5
2019-09-09 ---- 35

Select Ddate,Sum(MeterValue) as SumToday From @MyTable
group by Ddate
```

Sum for current date:

```
Ddate      ---- SumToday
2019-09-11 ---- 60
2019-09-10 ---- 45
2019-09-09 ---- 50
```

This is the final table that i want to achieve:

```
Ddate      ---- SumToday ---- SumYesterday ---- difference
2019-09-11 ---- 60       ---- 45           ---- 15
2019-09-10 ---- 45       ---- 50           ---- -5
2019-09-09 ---- 50       ---- NULL         ---- 50
```

Please note I am only interested in the difference column and a solution without the column "SumYesterday" is acceptable.

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a query that will give you the answer

```
select Ddate, SumToday, SumYesterday, SumToday - SumYesterday as [Difference]
from (
   select t.Ddate
     ,sum(t.MeterValue) as SumToday
     ,(select sum(MeterValue) from @MyTable t2 where t2.Ddate = dateadd(day, -1, t.Ddate)) as SumYesterday
   from @MyTable t
   group by t.Ddate) t
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lag()` directly in a `group by` query:

```
select Ddate, Sum(MeterValue) as SumToday,
       lag(sum(MeterValue)) over (order by Ddate) as prev_day,
       (sum(MeterValue) - lag(sum(MeterValue, 1, 0)) over (order by Ddate)) as diff
From @MyTable
group by Ddate;
```

Note:  This assumes that "yesterday" is always available.  If not -- and you really mean yesterday rather than the previous day -- then more logic is needed:

```
select Ddate, Sum(MeterValue) as SumToday,
       (case when lag(Ddate) over (order by Ddate) = dateadd(day, -1, Ddate)
             then lag(sum(MeterValue)) over (order by Ddate)
        end) as prev_day,
       (case when lag(Ddate) over (order by Ddate) = dateadd(day, -1, Ddate)
             then sum(MeterValue) - lag(sum(MeterValue, 1, 0)) over (order by Ddate)
        end) as diff
From @MyTable
group by Ddate;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your query as a CTE and self join it:

```
with cte as (
  select Ddate, sum(MeterValue) as SumToday from tablename
  group by Ddate
)
select 
  c1.*, c2.SumToday as SumYesterday, c1.SumToday - coalesce(c2.SumToday, 0) difference
from cte c1 left join cte c2
on c2.Ddate = c1.Ddate - 1
order by c1.Ddate desc
```

Or with `lag()` window function:

```
with cte as (
  select Ddate, sum(MeterValue) as SumToday from tablename
  group by Ddate
)
select *,
  lag(SumToday) over (order by Ddate) as SumYesterday, 
  SumToday - coalesce(lag(SumToday) over (order by Ddate), 0) as difference
from cte 
order by Ddate desc
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f2d18c458f5125c1920cbba793b18ddf).
Results:

```
Ddate               | SumToday | SumYesterday | difference
:------------------ | -------: | -----------: | ---------:
11/09/2019          |       60 |           45 |         15
10/09/2019          |       45 |           50 |         -5
09/09/2019          |       50 |              |         50
```